# Symfony - The file could not be found during update

Tags: php, symfony

I created an entity *Document* with a list of attributes including *file* attribute, while adding a document goes very well, when i update i get the validation error :

> The file could not be found.

*file* attribute must be required while adding but optional in edit, because i can just keep the old file.

Here is a part of my entity Document :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="document")
 */
class Document
{
    ...

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\File(maxSize = "5M", mimeTypes = {"application/pdf"})
     * @ORM\Column(name="file", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $file;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Dtype", inversedBy="documents")
     */
    private $dtype;

...

public function uploadFile($path, $type='', $oldFile=null)
{
    $file = $this->getFile();
    if ($file instanceof UploadedFile) {
        if(!empty($type)){
            $path = $path. '/' . $type;
        }
        $fileName = md5(uniqid()).'.'.$file->guessExtension();
        $file->move($path, $fileName);
        $this->setFile($type. '/' .$fileName);
        if($oldFile !== null){
            $oldFilePath = $path .'/'. $oldFile;
            if(file_exists($oldFilePath))
                unlink($oldFilePath);
        }
    }else{
        $this->setFile($oldFile);
    }

}
```

and in Controller i have :

```
public function editAction(Request $request, Document $document) {
    $oldFile = $document->getFile();
    $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\DocumentType', $document);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $document->uploadFile($this->getParameter('documents_file_dir'), $document->getDtype()->getChemin(), $oldFile);
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($document);
        $em->flush();
    }
...
}
```

Any help please ?

---

**EDIT**

The behavior iam wondering while a document is updated :

**If** the user has updated the file, then the file attribute must be validated with @Assert\File,

**Else** the file attribute will not be validated, so i can keep the original file uploaded while creating the document.

Answer (score 5):

Use the [validation groups](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/groups.html).
Mark field as required file only for create a new document:

```
/**
 * ...
 * @Assert\File(maxSize = "5M", mimeTypes = {"application/pdf"}, groups = {"create"})
 * ...
 */
private $file;
```

And specify relevant group for create and edit actions:

```
public function editAction(Request $request) {
    // ...
    $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\DocumentType', $document, ["create"]);

// ...

public function editAction(Request $request, Document $document) {
    // ...
    $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\DocumentType', $document, ["edit"]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in case i used the validation groups you mentioned, of course I'll be able to update the field, but in case the user had updated the file, it will not be validated as a file.

Comment: Hmm, you hold filename and uploaded file instance in same place ($file property). So, while document editing, handleRequest() method replaces old file name by value from form. Empty value should not cause error (validator just skip this constraint). But error message says that value is not empty: same error caused by invalid file name (FileValidator also handles strings as file names). Please, check bounded value in $file property while edit (after handleRequest() and before isValid() calls).

Comment: In Symfony submitted forms can't be edited, so it will always be non valid. In your case you always create two separate attributes one for file string and the other one for the uploaded file instance ?

Comment: Attributes separating for a form may simplify validation and other things. You even may separate objects: perhaps you need to use DTO (not Doctrine document) as model of form: https://ocramius.github.io/doctrine-best-practices/#/54 (see next slides). This way requires more code, but makes it more clear.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i'll try DTO method.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem but in the documentation, there is the answer :
https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html

> When creating a form to edit an already persisted item, the file form type still expects a File instance. As the persisted entity now contains only the relative file path, you first have to concatenate the configured upload path with the stored filename and create a new File class:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
// ...

$product->setBrochure(
    new File(_YOUR_UPLOAD_DIRECTORY_.'/'.$product->getBrochure())
);
```

Add it just before your createForm

```
$document->setFile(
    new File(_YOUR_UPLOAD_DIRECTORY_.'/'.$document->getFile())
);
$form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\DocumentType', $document);
```

Hope to resolve your problem.

Comment: many thanks for sharing, i managed to resolve the problem by adding an extra attribute $fileTmp (not mapped), it looks like it's the common way to deal with file uploading in Symfony. well your approach is a good solution too., regards

Answer (score 0):

The @Timurib answer got me in the right direction but the code did not exactly work for me for Symfony 3.2.6
What worked for me was:

```
/**
 * ...
 * @Assert\File(maxSize = "5M", mimeTypes = {"application/pdf"}, groups = {"create"})
 * ...
 */
private $file;
```

which was the same as the above answer and the different part is specifying the groups at the createForm:

```
public function editAction(Request $request) {
    // ...
    $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\DocumentType', $document, ["validation_groups" => "create"]);

// ...

public function editAction(Request $request, Document $document) {
    // ...
    $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\DocumentType', $document, ["validation_groups" => "edit"]);
```